# R Shiny: Accessing input reactive from dynamic selectInput in multilayer reactive setup

Tags: r, neo4j, shiny, reactive-programming, ggvis

PROBLEM SYNOPSIS: I have a shiny app I am building where I am trying to support database calls that drive dynamic lists of choices for selectInputs and where that dynamic input drives what a ggvis plot shows.  The dynamic selectInput is not correctly selected and filtering the ggvis plot

QUESTION: How can I support dynamic drop down lists while still ensuring my ggvis plot filters based on the chosen item?

PROBLEM DETAIL:

Within my Server.R file I have a reactive that grabs a slice of data from the database.  The get_chunk function is a call to NEO4J that I know works:

```
shinyServer( function(input, output, session) {

CURRENT_CHUNK <- reactive({
    #call NEO4J
    chunk <- get_chunk(some_list = input$chunk)
    return(chunk)
})
```

I also have a reactive that simply filters down the data based on the ui choices on the front end. The input$A value is the chosen value from a dynamically built dropdown list.  The filter_reactive is below.  NOTE: I've separated these two so I don't have to call the database all the time; only when I choose a different CHUNK.  The filter reactive looks like the following:

```
NO_DB_REACTIVE <- reactive({
    #react to current_chunk and pull back a chunk.
    filter_down <- CURRENT_CHUNK()
    #check for nulls
    if (!is.null(chunk)) {
        if (input$A != "All") {filter_down <- filter_down %>% filter(A == input$A)}
        return(filter_down)
    }
  return(filter_down)
})
```

The input$A value is generated dynamically as follows within the server.R file:

```
# reactively /dynamically generated the choices for the channel owners
output$owner_choices <- renderUI({ selectInput("A", "FOR Owner"
                                               , as.list(c("All",unique(CURRENT_CHUNK()[,'owner'] )))
                                               , "All") })
```

I also have a reactive that generates my GGVIS plot that looks like the following:

```
#All of the visualizations
MY_VIS <- reactive({

  # Lables for axes
  yvar_name <- names(display_choices)[display_choices == input$yvar]
  xvar_name <- names(cat_choices)[cat_choices == input$xvar]

  #retrieving 
  yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$yvar))
  xvar <- prop("x", as.symbol(input$xvar))

  CURRENT_CHUNK %>% 
    ggvis(x = xvar, y = yvar) %>%
    layer_bars() %>% 
    add_axis("x", title = xvar_name, properties = axis_props(labels = list(angle = 45, align = "left", fontSize = 10))) %>%
    add_axis("y", title = yvar_name) %>%
    set_options(width = 900, height = 300)
})
```

I tried to slim this down as much as possible.  There is some dynamic choosing of axes there but you get the point.  Notice I currently call CURRENT CHUNK within the MY_VIS reactive.  And the end of the file has these:

```
output$table <- renderDataTable({ NO_DB_REACTIVE() }) 
MY_VIS %>% bind_shiny("my_vis")
```

1. When I filter items this way I get no errors.  My table filters on input$A changes and the vis does not; I want the vis to change based on what input$A is as well.
2. I originally tried having MY_VIS depend on NO_DB_REACTIVE.  This fails as input$A is never generated. I guess because CURRENT_CHUNK never runs as it doesn't have to.  Notice the output$owner_choices is generated by reacting to CURRENT_CHUNK() not NO_DB_REACTIVE().

KEY QUESTION: How can I set this up so my input$A value is available when I  want to filter my ggvis plot?